# Editing Go(lang) code freezes PC

Tags: debugging, golang

Everytime I open a golang file and start editing, (even a file with just the following in)

```
package models

import "github.com/gofrs/uuid"

type Client struct {
    ID            uuid.UUID `db:"id"`
    Name          string    `db:"name"`
}
```

... emacs will slow down to a crawl, eventually freezing my entire PC. If I'm lucky I can quickly open a terminal and do `xkill`, most of the time I have to hard-reset my PC.

Right now, this is only happening with Go files, and I'm forced to use VSCode just to get work and deadlines done.

I'm using

```
GNU Emacs 28.1
```

I'm using doom emacs, with the following plugins:

```
;;; init.el -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(doom! :input

       :completion
       company           ; the ultimate code completion backend
       ivy               ; a search engine for love and life

       :ui
       doom              ; what makes DOOM look the way it does
       doom-dashboard    ; a nifty splash screen for Emacs
       doom-quit         ; DOOM quit-message prompts when you quit Emacs
       fill-column       ; a `fill-column' indicator
       hl-todo           ; highlight TODO/FIXME/NOTE/DEPRECATED/HACK/REVIEW
       hydra
       modeline          ; snazzy, Atom-inspired modeline, plus API
       nav-flash         ; blink the current line after jumping
       ophints           ; highlight the region an operation acts on
       (popup +defaults)   ; tame sudden yet inevitable temporary windows
       ligatures         ; ligatures or substitute text with pretty symbols
       treemacs          ; a project drawer, like neotree but cooler
       vc-gutter         ; vcs diff in the fringe
       vi-tilde-fringe   ; fringe tildes to mark beyond EOB
       window-select     ; visually switch windows
       workspaces        ; tab emulation, persistence & separate workspaces

       :editor
       (evil +everywhere); come to the dark side, we have cookies
       file-templates    ; auto-snippets for empty files
       multiple-cursors  ; editing in many places at once
       snippets          ; my elves. They type so I don't have to
       word-wrap         ; soft wrapping with language-aware indent

       :emacs
       dired             ; making dired pretty [functional]
       electric          ; smarter, keyword-based electric-indent
       vc                ; version-control and Emacs, sitting in a tree

       :term
       eshell            ; a consistent, cross-platform shell (WIP)

       :checkers
       syntax              ; tasing you for every semicolon you forget
       spell             ; tasing you for misspelling mispelling
       grammar           ; tasing grammar mistake every you make

       :tools
       ansible
       docker
       editorconfig      ; let someone else argue about tabs vs spaces
       (eval +overlay)     ; run code, run (also, repls)
       lookup              ; navigate your code and its documentation
       magit             ; a git porcelain for Emacs

       :lang
       data              ; config/data formats
       elm               ; care for a cup of TEA?
       emacs-lisp        ; drown in parentheses
       go                ; the hipster dialect
       lsp
       (go +lsp)
       (haskell +dante)  ; a language that's lazier than I am
       javascript        ; all(hope(abandon(ye(who(enter(here))))))
       markdown          ; writing docs for people to ignore
       org               ; organize your plain life in plain text
       python            ; beautiful is better than ugly
       sh                ; she sells {ba,z,fi}sh shells on the C xor
       web               ; the tubes

       :email

       :app

       :config

       (default +bindings +smartparens))
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**

It looks like `flycheck` might be the culprit, whenever it tries to check the file it consumes all resources on my machine. Sometimes it will "pause" itself, where I then have a brief moment to quickly kill the window.

I also disabled flycheck for go files only, and then I'm able to edit everything as normal. But then I miss out on the checking and formatting features.

Answer (score 1):

OK, turns out the issue was not directly related to Emacs.

What was causing the crash was `golangci-lint`. That application was crashing because it was a very old version, incompatible with my go version. I installed the new version and everything was sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on doom emacs configuration, but it seems to me that lsp-mode is not enabled.
Without lsp-mode, go-mode uses godef which does not work very well with go modules, https://github.com/rogpeppe/godef/issues/114

Comment: Thx. I tried adding lsp-mode and also added `(go +lsp)` to my tools. Unfortunately this still doesn't resolve the issue. I added some update notes to my original post. Looks like Flycheck might be to blame.